# Can I set the parent container as overflow: hidden but only specific child elements behave as if the parent is overflow: visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two child elements that are select field dropdowns inside of a parent container. The parent container is a modal I made for my project.  I also have other children elements such as a title, text, and a button.  I only want my two select field dropdowns to behave as if the parent container's overflow is set to visible but the children elements behave as if the parent container's overflow is set to hidden.

Essentially I want my drop downs to be visible outside of the parent when a user clicks the select field and the dropdown drops. While the other children are clipped within the parent container when I minimize the modal.  I had 'modal-container' initially set to overflow: visible so my dropdowns were visible outside of the parent but when I minimized my modal, the rest of the children elements were visible outside of my parent container.

Here's a general layout:

```
 <div className="modal-container">
      <div className="modal-inner-container">
        <h4 className="modal-header">header</h4>
        <div className="modal-text">
           <p>some text</p>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-dropdown-container">
           <div className="modal-dropdown></div>
           <div className="modal-dropdown></div>
        </div>
        <button className="modal-button">
      </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to pull this off? I would need my dropdowns to be in between my text div and button so position absolute doesn't apply in this case if I want my dropdowns relative to them.

I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: That's not going to be possible, since `overflow` is a single property from the container, no exceptions allowed. You could add the drop downs with javascript on top of your overlay, thats seems like the only viable solution to accomplish this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you can do this with `position: absolute;` 'on the children you want to overflow. Take a look at this example I made.

```css
.contain {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
 <div class ="child1">one</div>
 <div class ="child2">two</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, child 2 expands beyond its parent even though the parent has an overflow that's hidden.

Comment: Cool, but this only works because the wrapping box has no position property? It feels pretty fragile, any other CSS and it breaks... Hard to control.

Comment: That is correct.  Other wise I don't believe it is possible.

Comment: I do like that this works though - I really expected overflow to be... immutable. This has shown that you can escape it, but only in very particular circumstances.+1 since it is a solution, though my caveat remains :)

Comment: Glad it was of some use to you :).